# How to Use Clear Transformation in Indesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I've stared to learn indesign recently and i want to know what the command named "clear transformation" in object menu and an example to use it as it gives no result when i click it , thanks in advance [image]

Answer (score 2):

"Clear Transformations" resets the following values back to zero or 'normal':

1. Scale
2. Rotation
3. Shear
4. Flip horizontal/vertical

i.e., all transformations listed in the Object menu under "Transform", except for "Move". Naturally, if these values already all *are* 0, the command appears to do 'nothing'.

See also [InDesign Help / Transform objects](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/transforming-objects.html#clear_transformations) (and you really should have looked there first).

Answer (score 0):

Circle is not a good object because any transformation you do to it (apart from scale and shear) is not, hmmm, visible. Because it's a circle.

But to answer Clear Transformation works like "undo". It clean any transform you applied to object.